# "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I {am / was} busy"

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

I was teaching ESL class and came across a sentence "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I was too busy". A student in the class asked the reason why "I was too busy" is used instead of "I am too busy".

Answer (score 7):

Verbforms in a conditional like this, employing what we used to call "reported" speech, without direct quotation, will be shaped by the context—specifically, the verbform in the clause representing the speech will depend on whether the hypothetical "scopes" over the subordinate clause.

> **A:** What would you say if I asked you to have dinner tonight?
>   **B:** I would apologize and say that I'm too busy—I have papers to grade.

Here the context is a question about B's hypothetical action (*what **would** you say*) respecting a possible and knowable future action. Since as a matter of **actual** fact B is not free, she responds with an ordinary indicative.

> **C:** You don't know how to say No. If you were really really busy and I asked you to dinner, you'd go, even if it meant staying up all night grading papers.
>   **B:** That's not true. I would apologize and say I was too busy.

Here the context is an allegation about B's hypothetical action (*you **would** go*) in a hypothetical situation (*if you **were** busy*). Since B's denial does not reflect an actual situation but a **hypothetical** situation, she responds with a past form—what the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls a "modally remote" use of the past.

Comment: I don't think this is very clear. Are you saying that the form is decided by the question that was asked? The 2nd B (did you mean D?) could be: That's not true. I would apologize, and say "I am too busy".

Comment: @DCShannon 1) I'm saying the verbform employed is conditioned by the scope of the hypothetical. In the second the context is "If you **were** busy" 2) I meant B--same speaker, different context. 3) I said *reported* speech (which at least in my day meant paraphrased speech, not quoted speech), the same form as OP employs.

Comment: 1) Still not super clear. Might want to lower the jargon level, we're not all commercial writers. 2) So, you're saying "reported speech" is some kind of term, and that it differs from quoted speech. So, in my answer, would the first be reported speech, because they're describing speaking in the third person? 3) I now notice that A is asking about a hypothetical in the future, and C is asking about a hypothetical at an unspecified time. This is the difference you're highlighting?

Comment: @DCShannon  1) Lemme play with it. 2) Ayup. The current jargon for nonquotational speech keeps shifting -- reported, indirect, periphrastic. 3) Ayup.  "If you asked me if I'm free tonight I'd say I'm not." "If you asked what I'd say if I were busy, I'd say I was busy."

Answer (score 1):

It could be either, depending upon whether the speaker is describing their state at that time: I was too busy, or quoting what they would have said at that time: "I am too busy".

So, in other words, you have these options:

- If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you (that) I was too busy.
- If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you "I am too busy".

Answer (score 0):

*"If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I [to be] too busy"*

There are several possibilities:

1a. "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you 'I am too busy'"  -  This is reported speech.

1b.  "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I am too busy"  - This is reported speech where the secondary quotes are implied.

2a. "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I was too busy" -  This is the past tense of the sentence  "If you **ask** me, I **will** apologize and tell you I **am** too busy"

2b. "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I was too busy" -  This tells us of a habitual action in the past. It is equivalent to "I used to apologise"

3. "If you asked me, I would apologize and tell you I was too busy" - This suppresses the duplicated 'I would' of the sentence
   "If you asked me, I would apologize and (I would) tell you I was too busy"

All are valid. The meanings are subtly different.
You choose!