# Is it idiomatic to say "If he knew where we are, he would be here by now"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Supposing you're hiding from some intrusive relative,
"If he knew where we are, he would be here by now"

I think the part "where you are" is beyond the hypothetical scope, so I don't need to say "...where we *were*"? Am I right?

This answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61364/if-you-asked-me-i-would-apologize-and-tell-you-i-am-was-busy/61366#61366) seems to agree with me.

Comment: What part of that answer agrees with you? Too confusing to figure out.

Comment: It says "the verb form in the clause representing the speech will depend on whether the hypothetical "scopes" over the subordinate clause.", so I guess this is the case in my example. Right?

Comment: The speaker believes that "he" does *not* know where they are.  So the verb in the *if* clause is backshifted to **knew** and the subordinate clause will have **were**.  **were** in this particular example is far more common than **are**, at least in American English.  This isn't reported speech but a counterfactual scenario.

Comment: @TimR but "his" knowing is the only thing that is counterfactual, our being in a particular place is factual. So, why change the factual "where we are" to "where we were"?

Comment: @Let   Why?  I suppose it's because "our"  actual location is filtered through his lack of knowledge of it.  But it's what people say. Cf. *If he knew what my phone number **was**, he would call me.*  vs   *Since he knows what my phone number **is**, I expect him to call.*

Comment: @TimR There is no backshifting. The verb know is just in the simple past.//If he knew where we were=the entire thing is counterfactual. Not just "if he knew".

Comment: @Lambie You are mistaken. His *present* knowledge is being questioned with "If he **knew**..." and  my *present* phone number is being expressed  with "what my phone numnber **was**".   It's *he **would call** me* not *he **would have called** me*.

Comment: @TimR No, "If he knew" **is not present knowledge**. It's hypothetical knowledge. I don't know where he is now. **If** knew where he was now, I'd go there.

Comment: @Lambie It can be counterfactual or hypothetical. Counterfactual: he doesn't know your number. Hypothetical: he'd call if he knew it (e.g. you don't want him to bother you and haven't given your number to him). And you've missed my point about time. The difference between "he would call me" and "he would have called me" is the time context for the utterance. If the call failed to happen last week, say, we could say "If he knew (or had known) what my number was, he would have called me" and if the call *is failing to happen* today we could say "If he knew what my number was, he would call me".